# Avoid warning in wrapper around printf

Tags: c, string, compiler-warnings, string-literals

I have an error reporting functionality in my little C library I'm writing. I want to provide an `errorf` function in addition to the plain `error` function to allow embedding information in error messages easily.

```
/*
 * Prints a formatted error message. Use it as you would use 'printf'. See the
 * 'sio_error' function.
 */
void sio_errorf(const char *format, ...) {
    // Print the error prefix                           
    if (g_input == STDIN) fputs("error: ", stderr);
    else fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", g_progname);

    // Pass on the varargs on to 'vfprintf'. 
    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, format);
    // This may produce the following warning -- ignore it:
    //     warning: format string is not a string literal
    vfprintf(stderr, format, arglist);
    va_end(arglist);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
}
```

The problem is, I get this warning (compiling with clang 4.0 with the `-Weverything` switch):

> warning: format string is not a string literal

I understand why doing this would be bad. Is there any way I can get rid of this warning? Can I somehow enforce that the `format` argument `sio_errorf` be a string literal, so that the compiler knows that it always will be, and that I'm simply passing it on?

I know I can use `-Wno-format-nonliteral`, but only if other people are going to manually compile it too, they won't do that. I'd rather something in the source code that silences the warning.

Ideally I would still get the warning if the string I passed to `sio_errorf` *actually* isn't a literal, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Which compiler, and what version, are you using?

Comment: Clang (`-v` tells me "Apple clang version 4.0"), although I'm pretty sure gcc gives the same warning.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using GCC or one of its relatives, try an attribute on the declaration:

```
void sio_errorf(const char *format, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));
```

To add the attribute to a definition, you can use this:

```
__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)))
    static void sio_errorf(const char *format, ...) {
      ....
```

Comment: Good thought! This is specifically provided by GCC for these situations.

Comment: Does this just go on the function protoype in the header? Not on the definition?

Comment: @Mk12 you can also apply it to a definition: `__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2))) static void sio_errorf2(const char *format, ...) { \n ...`. but if the attribute is not visible in the translation, then the compiler will not check your format/parameters. (will update answer)

Comment: @Justin: Oh ok—so, inferring from your use of the `static` keyword, the only time you would want to put it on the definition is when it's static and you don't even necessarily *have* a prototype? And otherwise it needs to be in the header if you want to, say, link against the compiled library from another program?

Comment: @Mk12 while it's *possible* to add the attribute specifier to the definition of an exported symbol -- the attribute does not change the symbol's name (not a linking issue, iow). you normally *want* this attribute on the declaration (where it is separate from the definition) so that the format string and va arguments may be verified by the compiler. so it would not usually make much sense to hide this particular attribute by placing it on the definition when the function's declaration and definition are separate.

Answer (score 11):

Many compilers will allow you to set warning levels in one way or another. For example, gcc allows the control via `-W` flags on the command line when invoking the compiler.

Hopefully that's the compiler you're using since a program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    char *s = "xyzzy\n";
    printf (s);
    return 0;
}
```

generates the *exact* message you describe (assuming you've enabled the warnings with `-Wformat` and `-Wformat-nonliteral`).

The particular command line argument you would be looking for is:

```
-Wno-format-nonliteral
```

which will prevent complaints about the use of non-literal strings in those functions.

However, you may be looking for something more fine-grained so it also allows you to specify the disposition of certain diagnostic messages on the fly *within* your code with pragmas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"
int main (void) {
    char *s = "xyzzy\n";
    printf (s);
    return 0;
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wformat-nonliteral"
```

If you compile that with `-Wformat -Wformat-nonliteral`, you *won't* see the warning, because you've told gcc to ignore that particular warning for the `main` function.

Later versions of gcc than the one I run have the following options:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

which will push and pop the state of the diagnostics. This gets around the problems in my code above where you might configure that warning as an *error* - my second pragma would change it into a warning.

The use of push/pop would allow restoration to its original disposition with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-nonliteral"
int main (void) {
    char *s = "xyzzy\n";
    printf (s);
    return 0;
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: As for the first part of your answer—sorry, I should have mentioned that I already know I can use `-Wno-format-nonliteral`. I can't force everyone else to, though. I'd rather be able to compile with `-Weverything` and have no warnings.

Comment: The second part of your answer does seem like what I want, though. I'm  currently comparing it with Justin's answer.