# C - Non-constant format string flag

Tags: c, static-analysis

I have following code:

```
if (my_condition_is_true){
    my_format_string = "Something %d, plus some_other_thing %lu"
}
else{
    my_format_string = "Something %d, plus some_other_thing %llu"
}

my_string_formatter(my_format_string, var1, var2)
```

This raises non-constant format string issue. I tried following,

```
my_string_formatter("%s" my_format_string, var1, var2)
```

But, this doesnot help

Any idea folks....

Comment: What's `my_string_formatter`?

Comment: how is var2 both a unsigned long and an unsigned long long? not sure you'll get an answer without a [mcve]

Comment: It's just a warning. When you know what you are doing, ignoring the warning may be your best option (you may be able to disable it altogether).

Comment: This is an annoying problem with gcc, you'd think it could figure out the very simple logic of the `if` statement

Comment: @pmg this is quite a useful warning flag for finding security vulnerabilities, e.g. cases where text from I/O can make it through into format-string processing

Comment: I agree it's a useful warning, hence the "know what you are doing" caveat.

Comment: @StoryTeller - my_string_formatter(const char *, ...)

Comment: how about declaring a new variable `const char* my_const_format_string = my_format_string;` after the if-else block and then call `my_string_formatter(my_const_format_string, var1, var2)`?

Comment: my_format_string already declared as const char *

Comment: A good answer depends on code not yet posted.  Need `var1, var2` and possibly the definition of `my_string_formatter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a non-constant 'format' string:

```
"Something %d, plus some_other_thing %lu"
```

From [here](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/CCPPOBJ/Non-constant+format+string):

> Passing a non-constant 'format' string to a printf-like function can
>   lead to a mismatch between the number of arguments defined by the
>   'format' and the number of arguments actually passed to the function.
>   If the format string ultimately stems from an untrusted source, this
>   can be used for exploits.

This is a warning about security.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I already looked into this site. My problem is how do I get around the issue.

Comment: @Emdadul it would be useful to include this info in your question, for those who are not familiar with this gcc flag

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning because

```
char* someString = someFunc();
printf(someString);
```

is a common error especially amongst beginners. If the string contains a format specifier or even unescaped percent signs, it's a pretty bad bug. If you're lucky, it's a segmentation fault, if not, it's a security hole.

If you really know what you are doing, you can disable the warning. (NB my compiler (clang) doesn't raise this warning even with `-Wall` which I found somewhat surprising). This answer might help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171222/169346

you add an attribute to your `my_string_formatter` function that tells the compiler that the first string is a format string. The attribute is likely non portable between compilers.

However, your two format strings have different types for the second parameter (one is `unsigned long` and the other is `unsigned long long`) but you pass the same two parameters in the call, no matter which format string is used. This is a bug and you are only getting away with it because `long` and `long long` are the same size on your implementation (I assume).